# Making automated 2D machine movement with C

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have this little project, that is a machine which movement in 2 Dimensions, "walking" 1 block at time. So I´m starting with programming and I would like to print the numbers in order, like the machine is in movement.

Like this:

X O O O O

O O O O O

O O O O O

O O O O O

then the next move would be

O O O O O

X O O O O

O O O O O

O O O O O

then go until the end of column, so it moves to another column and make the movement backyards,(or it could go for the first dot of the new column and repeat the movement )

What I´m doing is one matrix and trying to make a for loop with restrictions but it isn't working.. I'm new to C language as well.

Remember that for programming I just want to print each place, 1 by 1.

Another question: I´m thinking of buying a development board to do this, what do you think about it? =) should I develop a driver using linux?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: here is my code that crash, and sry for newbie question =S

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
    int num[625];
    int x,y,count;
    do
    { 
    printf("\n Inicializando... ");
    num[625]=num[count];
    count++;
    } 
    while (num[count]!= 25);
    if (num[count]=25)
    {
        do
        { 
        printf("\n Inicializando... ");
        num[625]=num[count];
        count++;
        } while (num[count]!= 25);

    }
    for (count=0;count<625;count++)
    printf (" %d",num[count]);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bit premature talking about Linux drivers if you are a novice C programmer. It takes a good deal of experience to write drivers for Linux. It would help us a lot of you posted the code you have problems with, and explained a bit more about "it isn't working"

Comment: @MatsPetersson I edited, now with my code =)

Comment: Could you also add the part about "it isn't working" - what does it do, and how is that different from what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this algo.

Change NR By will It is the no of rows or columns.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define NR 5

int main()
{
   int i,j,loop;
   for( loop=0; loop < NR*NR; loop++)
   {
      printf("Loop %d\n",loop);
      for(i=0;i< NR; i++)
      {
         for (j=0;j<NR;j++)
         {
            if ( loop == NR*j+i )  printf("X ");
            else                  printf("0 ");
         }
         printf("\n");
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably NOT the actual answer to your question, but:

```
int num[625];
...
    num[625]=num[count];
...
```

Is storing something in an array position that doesn't actually exist. And C being a fairly permissive language, you are simply writing to something else immediately after the array - probably `x`. This is most likely NOT what you wanted to do.

Some further comments on the code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
```

It's far from good to mix `stdio.h` with `iostream` (`iostream.h` is very OLD - if you are using a compiler that is standards compliant, then use `iostream` - however, since you also tagged this as C, rather than C++, I would suggest remove it altogether.

```
int main()
{
    int num[625];
    int x,y,count;
    do
    { 
    printf("\n Inicializando... ");
    num[625]=num[count];
```

Note that aside from my comment above about addressing outside the array, `num[count]` has never been set - it has whatever value happens to be in that memory - which is quite possibly just about any value in the integer range.

```
    count++;
    } 
    while (num[count]!= 25);
```

Since `num[count]` is not initialized, it may or may not ever be 25. Once `count` gets high enough, it will probably crash.

```
    if (num[count]=25)
    {
        do
        { 
        printf("\n Inicializando... ");
        num[625]=num[count];
        count++;
        } while (num[count]!= 25);

    }
    for (count=0;count<625;count++)
    printf (" %d",num[count]);
```

I've never been a great fan of more than two, maybe three consecutive empty lines in a function.

```
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that `if (num[count]=25)` actually sets `num[count]` to 25. So the loop will always happen twice?